# Merge tweets by minutes

Tags: r

Is it possible to merge tweets in 5 minutes intervalin R?

Bellow is a part of the tweets:

data[1:15 , ]

## A tibble: 15 x 2

date                text
                 
 1 2020-01-10 23:59:56 "Subscribe to @washingtonpost The Intersect by @abbyohlheiser for your fish content primer, then AMA because fis…

2 2020-01-10 23:59:55 "My latest EcoOptimism post asks \"Can We Be Hopeful\" about #ClimateChange in the new year. Inspiration from @G…

3 2020-01-10 23:59:47 "@MSNBC @maddow @washingtonpost @nytimes\n@CNN @CBSNews @NBCNews \nAny of y'all think this might be a slightly i…

4 2020-01-10 23:59:39 "Maybe if Golsteyn had done the right thing in the first place he wouldn't have to be concerned with getting his…

5 2020-01-10 23:59:39 ".@washingtonpost reports that today's #FireDrillFriday action was \"the start, organizers said, of broader move…

6 2020-01-10 23:59:38 "@washingtonpost Y’all are an army, alright. https://t.co/QZIYk9CTmv"

7 2020-01-10 23:56:29 "@GeorgeWillard9 @washingtonpost He was definitely a fan of killing brown and ppl with drone strikes.  Lots of M…

8 2020-01-10 23:59:38 "Thanks @petulad for this piece, covering both NoMa and the Union Station Great Hall.\nhttps://t.co/eGUPctNgoK"

9 2020-01-10 23:59:33 "\" 'Congress has long abdicated its responsibility as laid out in the Constitution to make the hard decisions w…

10 2020-01-10 23:58:45 "@OneEyeBlackJack @washingtonpost Yet another RW lie"

11 2020-01-10 23:59:24 "@chad_dawkins @washingtonpost Zero Facts"

12 2020-01-10 23:59:19 "Happy Friday!\n\nFacebook doesn’t want to face the facts https://t.co/dZykYez3Ty"

13 2020-01-10 23:59:08 "Surprise, Surprise: The DOJ’s Hillary Clinton Investigation Has Been a Bust\n\n#CorruptFourthEstate\n\n@CNN @MS…

14 2020-01-10 23:59:06 "@washingtonpost It's all a stinking commy plot. General Salami was the sacrificial lamb in plan hatch by Putin …

15 2020-01-10 23:58:49 "@ddale8 You mean Rudy Giuliani, Trump’s appointed cybersecurity expert, doesn't have it all under control? \n\n…

Comment: How would you want to merge the tweets? Combine all text, or just count the number of tweets in the five minute interval?

Comment: My purpose is to combine all the text. This is relatively easy. The difficult part, at least for me, is to combine them at specific intervals (i.e 1m, 5m, 10m, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `floor_date` from the lubridate package for this. Just specify the minutes. Example below uses 1 minute, but change the 1 into 5 and you round down to the nearest 5 minutes.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(date = floor_date(date, unit = "1 minutes")) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarise(text = paste(text, collapse = " "))


# A tibble: 3 x 2
  date                text                                                                                                                
  <dttm>              <chr>                                                                                                               
1 2020-01-10 23:56:00 "@GeorgeWillard9 @washingtonpost He was definitely a fan of killing brown and ppl with drone strikes. Lots of M…"   
2 2020-01-10 23:58:00 "@OneEyeBlackJack @washingtonpost Yet another RW lie @ddale8 You mean Rudy Giuliani, Trump’s appointed cybersecurit~
3 2020-01-10 23:59:00 "Subscribe to @washingtonpost The Intersect by @abbyohlheiser for your fish content primer, then AMA because fis… M~
```

Comment: That's it, I have to learn dplyr. Using base R the solution should be more complicated. Thank you.